# "Lock" character selection in python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

How would you create a pattern that would be able to take any character, but any subsequent characters should be the same as the first? For example, ax + bx + x, where a, b, and x can be any character, but the 'x' character must stay the same. 
I am trying to create a pattern to recognize quadratics(ax^2+bx+c), but I realized that with my pattern,  using 2 different letters would match the pattern.
The pattern:

```
 r"([\d+]*)([\D])\^2\+?\-?([\d+]*)([^\+\-\d])\+?\-?([\d+])+$"
```

Comment: This isn't Python-specific, read up on regex syntax. You can use references to earlier capturing groups if you define them.

Comment: Play around here: regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a better job for a parser. Even if it's just for matching. However if you insist on using regex, then it can be done by doing:

```
^(?:\d+|\D)(\D)(?:[+\-*\/^](?:\d+\1?|\D\1?))+$
```

Which will match input like:

```
ax
ax+bx+x
ay+ay+y
ax^2+bx+c
```

It works by matching `\D` then capturing the subsequent `\D`. Then every time it finds 2 characters, the second character must be that previously matched character (`\D\1?`).

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/bkbb88/1)

If you want to be able to have stuff like `2+` beforehand. Then it gets a bit more tricky:

```
^(?:\d+[+\-*\/^](?:\d+[+\-*\/^])*)?\D(\D)(?:[+\-*\/^](?:\d+\1?|\D\1?))*$
```

Which will match input like:

```
ax
ax+bx+x
ay+ay+y
ax^2+bx+c
2+ax
2+ax+bx
2-1+ax+bx
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/pPJA0v/1)

If you need to match decimals and not just integers, then change those `\d+` into `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[+\-*\/^](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[+\-*\/^])*)?\D(\D)(?:[+\-*\/^](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1?|\D\1?))*$
```

Note that this doesn't take whitespaces into account, so you'd have to sprinkle a few `\s*` around if that is needed.